# How do toggle click event with focusout in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having form with couple of text boxes with focus in and focus out event. I am unable to fire click events on buttons because focus out event called once I lost writing from textboxes. How do fire click event to just after focus out?

```
$(document).on("focusout", ".fn-enlargeTextarea", function(event) {
     var optionNumber = ($(this).attr('id').replace('1option','')).trim();
     $('#1option'+optionNumber+'_counter').remove();
     $(this).removeClass('textarea-height01').addClass('textarea-height02');     
});
```

Comment: your image is helpfull but if you post your HTML script, it will be make easier for the others to help you bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `event.relatedtarget`

```
   $(document).on("focusout", ".fn-enlargeTextarea", function(event) {
     var optionNumber = ($(this).attr('id').replace('1option','')).trim();
     $('#1option'+optionNumber+'_counter').remove();
     $(this).removeClass('textarea-height01').addClass('textarea-height02');  
     var targetEvent = event.relatedTarget;
     $(targetEvent).click();
});
```